# Is there a word/phrase for Pre-Academia?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that means pre-academia. Academia is the establishment of those engaged in higher education (mostly graduate students and up), so pre-academia would be those engaged in lower education (mostly K-8, high school, and undergraduates). **Is there a word/phrase that means this?**

Comment: I've never heard of *academia* being isolated to graduate students and up.

Comment: @guifa Got it from [this answer](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17/just-how-high-is-higher-education/18#18) on Academia.SE

Comment: Yeah, most people in the US would interpret "academia" to refer to any college-level activities, from freshman to doctorate.  I'm trying to remember the "standard" word for K-12 schools, but it's not coming to me.

Comment: The *Academia SE* answer to which you link does not at all imply that *academia* refers exclusively to the graduate level study and above, merely that an SE with that for its title is likely to draw mainly graduate students and faculty as participants. And for what it is worth, in my experience, liberal studies at secondary level are frequently termed *academic[s]* in contradistinction to vocational training.

Comment: *Higher education* is all college/university, including at undergrads. Its logical antonym is *lower education*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US:

- Primary School - Grades Pre-Kindergarten to 5 (or 6) - Elementary School
- Middle School - Grades 5-7 (or grades 6-8) - Elementary School
- Secondary School - Grades 6 (or 7) to 12 - High School
- Post Secondary - College, University (undergraduates) 'Academia' starts here in the US.
- Post Graduate - Masters and Doctoral studies
- Post Doctoral - academic work done after completion of Doctoral studies, depending on the discipline.

Comment: When I did my Masters, it was called a post-graduate programme, and included a post-graduate Diploma for those who dropped out before the dissertation. Work done after completing a PhD is called post doctoral.

Comment: I am from California, and we never use the words "primary school or middle school or secondary school or post secondary."  I really wonder if you are American, unless the east coast uses those words and not the west coast.

Comment: It's called *tertiary education*, not "post secondary".

Comment: @Michael The complement of West Coast is not East Coast: it's most of America.

Comment: Actually, the State of California very much does use those words:http://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/gs/em/frstcls.asp

Comment: @tchrist Finding an obscure document on a government website doesn't prove anything.  I've lived in California all of my life, have you?

Comment: @Michael: you may have lived your entire life in California, but you obviously know nothing about [San Francisco](http://www.sfusd.edu/en/schools/middle-schools.html). Or [Los Angeles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Los_Angeles_Unified_School_District_schools#Middle_schools_.28grades_6-8.29). (At least, with respect to their schools).

Comment: do a google search : "san francisco primary schools" and then do "san francisco elementary schools" ..  first search result has 1000 listings..  2nd search result has 3000 listings.  clearly, even in San Francisco, use of elementary schools is more popular.  You obviously don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Michael: you just said *"we don't use the word middle school"* in California. I posted links to two pages containing a list of a dozen public schools in San Francisco and maybe fifty public schools in Los Angeles with the words "*Middle School*" ***in their name***. Who doesn't know who he's talking about?

Comment: In the U.S., even in California, grade 6-8 schools are called *middle schools* and grade 7-8 or 7-9 schools are called *junior high schools*. Which one you have depends on your school district.

Comment: @PeterShor   I updated my answer to state that it is "less common" instead of "never", as apparently there are exceptions.

Comment: Boys, boys, calm down now or I'll send you to the Head of School's office. @RoaringFish: thanks for the clarification; I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The word is generally "postgraduate" not "post graduate", also it's a rather uncommon term in the United States, where the term is usually "graduate" (as in "graduate studies", "graduate student", etc,). There are exceptions, though, such as the Naval Postgraduate School in Monterey, California.

Answer (score 0):

In America, we don't say it like that.  We say high school students, if we are referring to students who are not yet in college.

We never say pre-academia or pre-university or pre-college, so using those terms would identify you as a non-native speaker.

Also:

In California, we use these terms:

Elementary School - grades 1-6
Junior high school - grades 7-8 or 7-9 depending.
High School - grades 9-12 or 10-12 depending.

NOTE:  In California, it is less common to use "primary school" or "middle school" or "secondary school" or "post secondary".  These words are being used commonly in many other states, apparently. Also, these words are commonly used in England. however.

Comment: Those aren't British terms! And I certainly know Californians who use them, too. Perhapps your experience is simply limited.

Comment: Primary , middle school, secondary school are definitely used in England commonly.  In Southern California, they are terms never used by locals.

Comment: google "primary school los angeles" and you will see "elementary schools" come up

Comment: I have close personal friends from that area who vehemently disagree with you. Then again, I am talking about adults. Plus this says your state knows more than you do: http://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/gs/em/frstcls.asp

Comment: I am 43 years old.  We don't have primary schools in California, we have elementary schools.  We don't have middle schools, we have high schools.  Please talk about a subject you know something about.

Comment: In the U.S., even in California, *junior high* is grades 7-8 or 7-9, and *middle school* is grades 6-8. Which one you have depends on your school district. Middle schools are quite common in California; both Los Angeles and San Francisco have middle schools and not junior high schools.